# Instagram API: get images in original orientation

Tags: php, instagram-api

I'm trying to get recent images from an Instagram API account, using the following code:

```
    function getRecentMedia( $UserId, $Token ) {
    $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'
        . $UserId
        . '/media/recent/?access_token='
        . $Token
    ;

    return $this->curlGet( $url );
}
```

curlGet simply does a curlRequest and returns the results. This request returns recent images, so long as I pass the userId and a token for the account I'm trying to access, but all the images are square, with white "letterboxing" at either the top and bottom or on the left and right. So, a typical post will include a 150x150 image, a 320x320, and a 640x640 image.

If I understand http://developers.instagram.com/post/128288227716/api-migration-for-landscape-and-portrait-formats , this feed should just return the images in their original orientation, but it isn't. The "Non Square Media" checkbox is checked on the developer page. Does anyone have any idea why the images would still be resized into perfect squares.

Does

Comment: did u click "non-square media" and click "update client" ?

Comment: Yes, and I verified in the instagram site that the images were uploaded in a non-square format. But, at the moment, the only thin coming across that does not have the dimensions listed earlier is videos.

Comment: is this for a particular user or all photos?

Comment: It's for a particular user. It's for a company's IG page, and we're using credentials for their account to try to access images on their page.

Comment: oh ok, you are the same guy from other questions, that user's photo is letter-boxed using another app and posted as square, so u cannot get landscape image. original photo is square, get it ?